# How this operation is called?

Tags: python

I'm trying to solve a problem that I believe is a standard Python task and has already been asked here, but I don't know the proper vocabulary term for it.

Given the structure

```
((['a'], t1), (['a', 'b', 'c'], t2), (['c', 'd'], t3))
```

and I need to get something like this

```
(('a', [t1, t2]), ('b', [t2]), ('c', [t2, t3]), ('d',[t3]))
```

out of given data. How to solve this task or at least what is the name of this operation?

Comment: What's `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d`, and `t1`, `t2`, and `t3`? If you meant strings, then please use quotes.

Comment: In fact these are the week days and t* are schedule time.

Comment: @VladT.: What type are they? Are they strings?

Comment: @LevLevitsky it doesn't matter what type they are.

Comment: @ZeroPiraeus Yes it does. The accepted answer may not work for all types of `a`-`c`.

Comment: @SukritKalra a-ds are unicode, ts are datetimes, but I don't think it matters.

Comment: @LevLevitsky Why not? Or could you point at some docs that explain why it may not?

Comment: If the type is unhashable, the accepted answer won't work.

Comment: What @SukritKalra said; only hashable objects can be dictionary keys. Mutable objects like lists and dicts are not hashable. Strings work just fine as keys though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
from collections import defaultdict

in_ = ((["a"], "t1"), (["a","b","c"], "t2"), (["c","d"], "t3"))
out = defaultdict(list)

for keys,val in in_:
    for key in keys:
        out[key].append(val)
```

which gives

```
{
    'a': ['t1', 't2'],
    'b': ['t2'],
    'c': ['t2', 't3'],
    'd': ['t3']
}
```

and I would call it something like a reference-list involution.

Answer (score 4):

This is called *pivoting* a table (or occasionally *reshaping*). Normally it's done with specialist data structures (namely, tables).

[See some Pandas documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reshaping.html) for a little overview.

Comment: Not so easy as I expected but that's what I need, thanks a lot.